# Autofocus (even focus) in Popup page?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

After many times of attempts, I found out that no matter what I do:

```
function foo(){
     $("input").focus();
}
<body onload="foo();">

<input type="text" autofocus tabindex="1">
```

I even used a hidden button that set focus on it and I programmitically click on it and It won't even focus on it in the popup page, and it is driving me *crazy*. I checked the code many times and I couldn't find a single error. So I really want to know if there's a actual possible way to achieve this, since this seems just like simple problem.

Comment: Browser action, user clicking on the icon.

Comment: I'm using `$('input:first').focus();` in a `browserAction` popup and it works as expected. Have you tried it in Chrome Canary incase it is a bug in your version of Chrome?

Comment: @abraham, nope, it still does not work. I put it in `onload=""`, and I am using Chrome 19.0.1036.7. Any ideas?

Comment: Interesting. I'm running the same version of Chrome and it works for me.

Comment: He's not the only one......  http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=111660  ...doesnt work for me either.

Comment: I think when a user clicks on the icon, the popup appears but do not focus no the popup automatically and that's why. Just guessing.

Answer (score 3):

This is no longer an issue on Chrome version 21. Other recent versions of Chrome might also have this [issue resolved](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=111660).

---

## Example

### manifest.json

```js
{
    "name": "Stackoverflow Popup Form Focus",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "version": "0.1",
    "description": "Simple popup with form with form element focused",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    }
}
```

### popup.html

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css" media="screen">
            body { width: 300px; height: 100px; text-align: center; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>This input should focus when this opens</p>
        Party Input: <input id='party-input'/>
        <script src="popup.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

### popup.js

```js
document.getElementById('party-input').focus();
```

## Running Example Screenshots

Clicking extension button with browser window opened to exampley.com

[image]

Example files http://mikegrace.s3.amazonaws.com/stackoverflow/popup-form-focus.zip